# What's the best recipe for installing 'just' qmail on centos 6.3

Tags: centos, email

I'm about to start a fresh install of qmail on Centos 6.3

I've used qmail for years as a standalone mail gateway, and have installed without a 'recipe' on Solaris for intel and last time I installed I followed the qmailrocks guides and just missed out the stuff I don't use like web interfaces and vpopmail etc...

Was wondering if there are other/better guides out there or are peeps still using QMR?

Comment: Who still uses qmail?

Answer (score 0):

Qmailrocks is pretty old as a guide and has a few errors in there. Visit jsm1.net and use the instructions there